# runCommand provider in msdeploy's Manifest.xml file

Tags: provider, msdeploy

I am trying to include running a batch script (more, provided I can figure this out) as part of the deployment process via msdeploy by using the runCommand provider in the manifest file.

This is what my manifest file looks like

```
<MSDeploy.iisApp>
  <iisapp path="Default Web Site/SiteName" />

  <dbfullSql path="msdeploy.config" transacted="false" />
  ...(more calls to providers)

  <runCommand path="(call to batch script here)" />
</MSDeploy.iisApp>
```

Everything in the manifest file runs fine, but it doesn't look like my command is actually running. A log of the outputs gives me this at the end where my command should have been called.

```
Info: Adding child runcommand (MSDeploy.iisApp/runCommand).
Verbose: The synchronization completed in 1 pass(es).
Total changes: 85 (82 added, 3 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes copied)
```

I use the following command to run msdeploy:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="package" -dest:iisApp="Default Web Site/SiteName" -setParam:name=bunch of parameters... -debug -verbose > MsDeployOutput.txt
```

The command I give to the manifest file (which is also in my source package) is recognized (in whatever way that may be) but never executed. Any ideas as to the cause and the solution?

Answer (score 3):

MsDeploy also has an auto provider which deploys the content of the package. So you will have to change your commandline to be

"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="package" -dest:auto -setParam:name=bunch of parameters... -debug -verbose > MsDeployOutput.txt

Also, if you want your manifest to kick in, you need to modify your commandline as

"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="package" -dest:manifest="manifestLocation" -setParam:name=bunch of parameters... -debug -verbose > MsDeployOutput.txt

and MsDeploy will do its magic.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in runCommand provider. To workaround it, use this attribute 
**MSDeploy.MSDeployKeyAttributeName="path"**

Like this: `<runCommand path="(call to batch script here)" MSDeploy.MSDeployKeyAttributeName="path" />`

Comment: As far as I can tell, if this bug existed, it is solved at this point (using 2.1, which looks like "2.0" on the IIS site).

Comment: This got my `<runCommand>` working when it didn't before and I'm using WebPI 3.0 and IISExpress 7.5.

Comment: This is still needed for me with WebPI and IISExpress 8.0